# How push into array without creating numbered indexes in a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: multidimensional-array, array-push

I want to use array_push() to add to an array, but it always adds a `[0] => Array` level. How can I prevent that, or take that out afterwards?

For example, I'm trying to push into the '[addOns] => Array' with this:

```
$addOnid='gcl1';
$addOnid_arr=array('inheritedFromId' => $addOnid);
array_push($result['addOns'], $addOnid_arr);
```

The array_push is resulting in this:

```
Array
(
    [addOns] => Array
        (
            [inheritedFromId] => gcl2
        )
        [0] => Array
            (
               [inheritedFromId] => gcl1
            )

)
```

And want to make it:

```
Array
(
    [addOns] => Array
        (
            [inheritedFromId] => gcl2
        )
        (
            [inheritedFromId] => gcl1
        )
)
```

...basically just getting rid of all the `[0] => Array`, moving all the subarrays up a level.

Maybe I haven't been using the right queries, but I haven't been able to find out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple just use this instead:

```
$addOnid = 'gcl1';
$addOnid_arr['addOns'][] = ['inheritedFromId' => $addOnid];
```

Comment: Same result, I get this:
```(
                    [addOns] => Array
                        (
                            [inheritedFromId] => gcl2
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [inheritedFromId] => gcl1
                                )

                        )

                )```

Comment: I'm rethinking this. Maybe the first 'inheritedFromId' should actually be numbered, so that the second one is sequential, and will stay in the same array level? Instead of trying to get rid of the numbering, go with it? So, I'd end up with: '( [addOns] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [inheritedFromId] => gcl2), [1] => Array ( [inheritedFromId] => gcl1 ) ) )'

Comment: @jamminjames it must be numbered. or you can use $addOnid as the array key instead

Comment: Okay, it's becoming clear now. What I thought was a bug was actually a feature. I was trying to create the array in a faulty way. Newbie alert! Thanks.

Comment: @jamminjames no problem and that's how you learn.. also please accept the answer if it helped you